# I've stolen money when i was younger, now what?

Tags: theft, debt

Salam, I'm going to avoid the long sob story, I'm an adult now and take full responsibility for my actions. Without revealing too much about my crime, I'll try to describe things as simply as possible.

I needed money desperately for my family when i was ~15, So I scammed a lot of people out of a lot of money, $1500-$10k per transaction, dozens of these occurred. I'm now an adult, and the money helped put me through college, pay my family's medical expenses, and pay the bills. (We had no income, it was just me, my mother, disabled family member, and 3 younger siblings).

I've done extremely well for myself as an adult, but these victims have been on my conscious for a while. I've started retracing my steps, getting back into old emails, and such and reaching out to old victims. I've repaid some, but some are refusing to accept the money (out of anger or thinking I'm going to scam them again).

So my questions are:

1. How can i repay those refusing to accept my money (out of anger, fear, or lack of responses)
2. How can i repay those who have already passed away? (I fear some of the people that aren't responding may have actually passed away).
3. How can i repay those that i do not recall? Some victims i cannot find info on. I've tried to remember them all but i'm sure im missing a few.

Would like to make this right, so would like some guidance.

Comment: You could try to mail them checks or gifts if they refuse to take it from you. You can pay their heirs if they are deceased. If there is no way to pay someone then you can pay charity on their behalf.